# How to wrap a div around a div with CSS

Tags: css

Given some code like below, could someone show me how I could align the `content-meta-wrapper` inside of the `content` div at the TOP RIGHT corner and then have the content inside the `content` div wrap around it like in the image? The pink highlight in the image below is the `content-meta-wrapper` div.

```
<div id="content">
  all the content you see except the Half BOX in the right hand side


  <div id="content-meta-wrapper">
     <div id="content-meta>
       The right that is aligned at the TOP RIGHT of the content diva
     <div>
  <div>

</div>
```

[image]

The reason I can't just view source from the image is because the image is from how my site is now with moving some stuff around in Photoshop.

Comment: "Given some code like below" - all I see is a screenshot. Code plx.

Comment: sorry it didn't show up at first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it's marked up inside of the content `<div>`, you just need to pass [`float: right;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) to it, and it should do the trick.

The code I used in **[This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qbquw/)** is the following:

```
#container { /* Pure Looks */
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#floated {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right; /* This is what counts!! */
    background: red;
}
```

See this **[Awesome Article about Floats - by Chris Coyer of css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/)**

Answer (score 1):

You should use the css rules,

> float:left;
>
> float:right;

these will align your divs in the correct postion, to keep things tidy make sure to give your div's a width.